# How to limit the search results and hide the age of the results?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

So, I am doing APIs and Microservices course on FreeCodeCamp, and I am stuck on the last challenge where it says,
"
Find people who like burrito. Sort them by name, limit the results to two documents, and hide their age. Chain .find(), .sort(), .limit(), .select(), and then .exec(). Pass the done(err, data) callback to exec().
"
Link to the challenge: https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/apis-and-microservices/mongodb-and-mongoose/chain-search-query-helpers-to-narrow-search-results

my code so far:

```
var queryChain = function(done) {
  var foodToSearch = "burrito";
  Person.find({food:foodToSearch})
        .sort((a,b)=>{
    if(a.name>b.name) return 1
    else if(a.name<b.name) return 0
    else return 0
  })
        .limit(2)
        .select()
        .exec((err,data)=>{
    if(err) console.log(err)
    done(null,data)
  })
};
```

Can anyone help me on how to limit the search queries and hide the age?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I missed the part that making use of `select()` is necessary.

I am not sure why did you make your sort that complex. Mongodb is able to sort string.

```
var queryChain = function(done) {
  const foodToSearch = 'burrito';
  Person.find({food:foodToSearch})
        .sort({ name: 1 }) // -1 for descending
        .limit(2)
        .select({ age: 0 })
        .exec((err,data)=>{
          if(err) console.log(err);
          done(null, data);
        })
};
```

The above code should work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this code works. First of all, I made a mistake,naming the argument wrong. The key here should be,"favoriteFoods" instead of "foods". And selecting ('name favoriteFoods') hides the age.

```
var queryChain = function(done) {
  var foodToSearch = "burrito";
  Person.find({favoriteFoods:foodToSearch})
        .sort({ name:1 })
        .limit(2)
        .select('name favoriteFoods')
        .exec(done)
};
```

Comment: I missed the part that you must use select function. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked like a charm for me.

```
const person = Person.find({ favoriteFoods: foodToSearch });

person.sort({ name: 1 })
.limit(2)
.select('name favoriteFoods')
.exec(function(error, people) {
    if(error) return console.log(error);
    done(null, people);
})
```